# sublime text 3 ctrl backspace doesn't work

Tags: text, backspace, ctrl, sublimetext3

sublime text 3 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> doesn't work 
my sublime keymap like this but but still does not work

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+backspace"], "command": "delete_word", "args": { "forward": false } },
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please take your time to explain the problem.

Comment: Please include your platform as well in the question.

Comment: I'm on 64bit ubuntu 10.04 and it doesn't work.

Comment: Same here - I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, 64bit

Answer (score 1):

if it dosen't work for you, you can still make your own shorcut : go to preferences>KeyBendings User and define your own : for example

```
[
{ "keys": ["f1"], "command": "delete_word", "args": { "forward": false } }
]
```